# Rotation of a group of objects in Unity is too fast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a group of objects 90 degrees in unity, so I set all of the objects to the same parent, then rotated the parent, it rotated just fine but it's too fast that I can't see, how can I slow it down? I tried both of codes below and both are the same :\ this code appears in a function that is called by update when the user presses on a button

```
    float totalRotation = 0;
    while (Mathf.Abs(totalRotation) < 90){
        totalRotation += Time.deltaTime;
        Parent.transform.RotateAround(temp.transform.position, flag*Vector3.right, Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

and this one

```
    Parent.transform.RotateAround(temp.transform.position, flag*Vector3.right, 90f);
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: posting code fragments is **utterly useless**.  nobody has a clue where this code appears, etc.

Comment: @JoeBlow edited, hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a factor for the angle, something like

```
Parent.transform.RotateAround(temp.transform.position, flag*Vector3.right, Time.deltaTime * 0.5f);
```

Based on the `while` I would guess that you actually don't do this in `Update`. Either way this will not work since update is **one** frame. You don't want a `while` to do anything time related like this. Make your `while` an `if` instead. That way the rotation will probably be too slow so make the factor bigger. Currently your rotation is instant.

Edit:
Something like this would work:

```
public bool isRotating = false;
public float speed = 20.0f;

public Vector3 targetRotation;

void Update()
{
    if(isRotating)
    {
        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.eulerAngles, targetRotation) > 1.0f)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        } 
        else
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = targetRotation;
            isRotating = false; 
        }
    }
}
```

This would be around y only.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I turned it into an if and made the factor bigger, I just want it to rotate 90 degrees and tried many factors and none of them seems correct :\

Comment: Edited an example of how you could clamp the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

*This part of the answer doesn't work. Please see the update*

Actually you did it in the wrong way. Movements in Unity should be done slowly through updates, not just once. Like ChristophKn, I suggest using Coroutine.

```
const float speed = 180;
IEnumerator Rotate () {
    float rotated = 0;
    while (rotated < 90) {
        float rotation = speed*Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        rotated += rotation;
        Parent.transform.RotateAround(temp.transform.position, flag*Vector3.right, rotation);
        //wait for the next fixed update to continue.
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate ();
    }
}
```

To start rotating, call `StartCoroutine(Rotate);`

**EDIT**

I have another idea to do this, not using script but animation:

- First, add a rotating animation to your parent objects, which rotates the angle you want.
- To rotate the group of objects, set them to that parent like you did in your question, then start the animation.
- At the end of the animation (you can call your methods at that point using [animation events](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html)), call `SetParent(null,true)` for all your objects in the group. This will remove the parent but keep the world position.
- Finally, set your parent's rotation to the original value.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried it and it did not rotate at all :( !

Comment: it didn't even get into the while loop, I added a print statement before and in the loop, it didn't reach the one inside it.

Comment: Ok ok, I fixed it, just a greater sign.

Comment: it rotated but not a full 90 degrees rotation :\

Comment: How much did it rotate? about 45 degree or something

Comment: thanks for your effort, it was solved by using a flag whenever I wanted something to rotate, then using the rotation code as above in Update function with if instead of while! I was stupid enough not to understand that Update is called once by frame! thanks anyways!